# Iterating a treemap for fixed number of times

Tags: java, iteration, treemap

If I have a treemap that contains string and double. Is there anyway to retrieve say first 10 keys from map?

Comment: Why can't you just call next() on the iterator ten times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fetch the iterator via `treeMap.entrySet().iterator()` if you want the key/value pairs or `treeMap.keySet().iterator()` if you just care about the keys, then call `iterator.next()` 10 times or as long as `iterator.hasNext()` returns `true`.

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Double>> firstTen = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Double>>(10);
Iterator<String, Double> iterator = treeMap.entrySet().iterator();
for (int i = 0; iterator.hasNext() && i < 10; i++) {
    firstTen.add(iterator.next());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not in the JDK but there are methods in 3rd-party libraries that do this.

For example `Iterables.limit` from [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

Comment: @Rushdi Shams, It's difficult to give an example without some context, e.g what do you want to do with those first 10 keys.

Answer (score 1):

Since a `TreeMap` is a `NavigableMap`, you should take a look at the methods in that interface. There's nothing that lets you select the first `n`, but you can select all entries with a key less than a given key, etc.

Otherwise, I would just use an `Iterator` and stop after `n` iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `entrySet()` in a List and create a `subList()`:

```
SortedMap<String,Double> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, Double>();
List<Entry<String, Double>> firstTen = 
    new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String,Double>>(treeMap.entrySet())
    .subList(0, 10);
for(Entry<String, Double> entry : firstTen){
    // do something with entries
}
```

Drawback: the entire map will be copied to the list.

Answer (score 0):

It worked with the code snippets provided by dkarp and sean. However, it worked with the suggestion of DJClayworth as well. Here is how I solved it:

```
    c=sorted_map.keySet();

    Iterator itr=c.iterator();
    String s="";
    while (i<iteratesize&&itr.hasNext()){
        s=(String) itr.next();
        System.out.println(s);
        s="";
        i++;
    }
```

Thank you very much everyone for your help. I really appreciate it.